# How can I display Font Awesome fonts in Character Map?

Tags: icons, fonts, unicode

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 x64, and I've just installed FontAwesome - firstly by running install on the `ttf` file, which I grabbed from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/; and secondly by discovering it's in the repo and running:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-font-awesome
```

Opening the font viewer I can see the fonts:

[image: FontAwesome in Font Viewer]

However, when I open the character map, I don't see them:

[image: FontAwesome in Character Map with Latin Script]

Should I be selecting any particular Script? I skimmed down the list to see if I can get to see the FontAwesome icons, but nothing jumped out at me.

What I am after is to find the unicode character code for particular icons. I know FontAwesome has a cheat sheet with the unicode's: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/, however, I'd like to be able to determine the codes from my system.

Another example is font-mfizz, which doesn't offer a similar cheat sheet (at least from what I can tell). I did however find that submitting the `woff` font - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DanBrooker/file-icons/master/resources/fonts/font-mfizz.woff - to the site http://www.pkmurphy.com.au/glyphviewer is able to print out the code points:

[image: font-mfizz code points]

Is this glyphviewer tool my best option?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Character Map</kbd>. Select the font and select <kbd>Character Details</kbd>

[image: Character Map > Character Details]

To find your character, use the view <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>By Unicode Block</kbd>. In <kbd>All</kbd> you have a very large list and in this list, you should find your character. But the font has 10FFFF (1114112<sub>10</sub>) characters. Without knowing the code, it's a little bit hard to find your needed character.

You can also filter it out so it only displays the glyphs/icons specific to this font. Go to <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Show only glyphs from this font</kbd>.

[image: view menu in Character Map]

Comment: Thanks for the tip on switching to Unicode Block - exactly what I want.

Comment: You mean the penguin?

Comment: I have three different *Awesome* fonts in my system, perhaps that's the reason.

Comment: Sorry... I noticed your screenshot is slightly different to the one I see, hence the different code.

Comment: @trent thanks for the edit, It's a great improvement. :)